# How to enable search option in the select drop-down in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to enable the search option in the select dropdown field in Angular 9.
I tried using '[NgxMatSelectSearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search)' and also using MDB Bootstrap but none of them seems to be working.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this functionality using 'Select2'

Install the below dependencies:

npm install select2
npm install jquery --save

In Angular.json add

```
"styles": [
       "node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css",
           ...
       ],
"scripts": [
       "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
       "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"
              ...
      ]
```

In the Component.ts file add

```
...
declare let $: any;
...
export class AppComponent {
...
   
   ngOnInit() {
    
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    $('.js-example-basic-single').on("change", function(){
     alert($(this).val());
    });
  }
...
}
```

And finally, add the below code into app.component.html file

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can someone tell me how to implement this without using jquery and select2?